# How define some PHP constant in the Symfony configuration?

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, yaml, constants

this is my first post, so i will try to be clear

So i need to define some constants in the Symfony configuration (in a .yaml file, i guess)
I know i could define them throw `public const MY_CONST` but that is not what I want.

I guess this is what i need (the second part, i am not using Abstract controller as i am not in a controller)

> https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html#accessing-configuration-parameters

But I just can't get it to work. Could anyone help me, by giving me an exemple, or maybe an other way to do ?

Thanks guys.

Comment: What is the nature of the information that needs to be defined? Is it a file path or an api key or something similar? I suspect what you need is either symfony's parameters or the more framework agnostic .env environment variables

Comment: @Kyrre it is just some strings (which will be used with sprintf() to becomes completes URL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters you described can be used in the configuration defined as eg;

```
parameters:
    the_answer: 42
```

You can then use these values in further configuration things (see below for example). Or if you want to handle these values in a controller you can (**not recommended anymore**) use `$this->getParameter('the_answer')` to get the value.

## Binding arguments (recommended):

This approach wil bind values which you can then get (*auto-magically* injected) in a controller function/service by referencing the argument.

The values can range from simple scalar values to services, .env variables, php constants and all of the other things the configuration can parse.

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            string $helloWorld: 'Hello world!'  # simple string
            int $theAnswer: '%the_answer%'      # reference an already defined parameter.
            string $apiKey: '%env(REMOTE_API)%' # env variable.
```

Then these get injected in a service/controller function when we do something like:

```php
public function hello(string $apiKey, int $theAnswer, string $helloWorld) {
    // do things with $apiKey, $theAnswer and $helloWorld
}
```

More details and examples can be found in the symfony docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#binding-arguments-by-name-or-type

## Inject into service (alternative)

You can also directly [inject it into the defined service using arguments](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#manually-wiring-arguments).

```yaml
# config/services.yaml
services:
    # explicitly configure the service
    App\Updates\SiteUpdateManager:
        arguments:
            $adminEmail: 'manager@example.com'
```

Comment: Perfect, taught me something new! Will move to binding from hereon.